# Generic method declaration

Tags: c#, generics

I have hierarchy of classes:

```
class A{}
class B: A {}
class C:B {}
```

is it possible to implement method in class A and it would be inherited by derived classes B and C and so on and that method should return value of class type?

```
A val = A.method(); (val is A)
B val = B.method(); (val is B)
C val = C.method(); (val is C)
```

And I don't want use of generics in call of this method, ie:

```
C val = C.method<C>();
```

Guys, excuse me, one elaboration, this method should be static.

I don't want to use generic in method istelf, because it forces to point type that method should return, whereas method should return type of its class.

```
class A
    {
      Method<T>()
      {
         T result;
         return result;
      }
    }
```

If I have such method I can change return type:

```
D result = A.Method<D>();
```

but I wanted it to return value of type A;

Comment: done. the language is c#

Comment: Let me as a question, what would happen if you wrote: var val = (C as A).method(); The point is, that such construct shouldn't be necessary in normal circumstances.

Comment: so you want `public B method(){}` in B and `public C method(){}` in C and you want the method to be defined in A, right?

Comment: Curious, why don't you want to use the generic in the method?

Comment: It looks like you want a static method? Is that so?

Comment: @AndreyKhataev Re your latest edit, if you return D and D inherits A, then you can use D as you would A...

Comment: "D" is there for any type not derived from A,B,C

Comment: @AndreyKhataev I have really lost the plot on what it is you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

To call the method like that it would have to be static, and static methods are not inherited.

Using `B.method()` to call a static method in `A` is the same as using `A.method()`. The compiler just uses the type to determine where the method is, but it's impossible for the method to know if it was called using the `A` or `B` type.

Answer (score 2):

Using some design patterns from C++ makes this easier:

```
class A
{
    protected virtual A method_impl() { return new A(); }
    public A method() { return method_impl(); }
}

class B : A
{
    protected override A method_impl() { return new B(); }
    public new B method() { return (B)method_impl(); }
}

class C : B
{
    protected override A method_impl() { return new C(); }
    public new C method() { return (C)method_impl(); }
}
```

Of course, this exact problem never arises in C++, which allows covariant return types for overrides.

---

Another way, using IoC pattern:

```
class A
{
    protected virtual void method_impl(A a) { a.initialize(); }
    public A method() { A result = new A(); method_impl(result); return result; }
}

class B : A
{
    public new B method() { B result = new B(); method_impl(result); return result; }
}

class C : B
{
    public new C method() { C result = new C(); method_impl(result); return result; }
}
```

Comment: Although `B.method()` returns a `B` instance, the return type is `A` so it still needs a cast: `B val = (B)(B.method());`.

Comment: @Guffa: Look again -- that's true of the protected `method_impl`, not the public method (unless called polymorphically through a base class handle).

Comment: @BenVoigt: I see, there is a method in B that shadows the method in A, which is what the OP specifically asked to avoid. So, -1 because the answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Guffa: Where does he ask to avoid that?  He asked to inherit behavior, and the behavior in the protected virtual method is inherited.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Read the question. The method is not implemented in A for the other classes, as the implementation is shadowed.

Comment: This both solutions lead to overriding this method in derived classes, which I wanted to avoid

Answer (score 2):

Use an extension method:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            B x = new B();
            x.Method();
        }
    }

    public static class Ext
    {
        public static T Method<T>(this T obj)
            where T : A,new()
        {
            return new T();
        }
    }

    public class A
    {

    }

    public class B : A
    {

    }
```

Or a variation thereof. Note that you must have some public member capable of creating an instance of the specified type. To expound, the compiler 'guesses' the value of the type parameter. The method is still generic, but generic syntax is nowhere to be seen when the method is called (usually).